# unable to get suggestions in qna maker after enabling active leaning filter by suggestions option

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

[image]

Hi,

I'm unable to get suggestions for qna pair in qna maker after enabling active learning feature, and when filter by suggestions is ON I'm getting the display as above. Though the qna pairs are added i can not see them after the filter by suggestion option is ON. So can you please suggest me how to solve this senario. I can get the answer for the qna pair while testing in bot framework emulator.

Thanks

Comment: Did you do anything in code, or you just turned the option on? I can't find the reference, but I read in the docs somewhere that suggestions will only appear when there are multiple, similar questions that don't have an exact answer. If you just have a couple of similar phrases or not that many over time, you won't get any suggestions. I think there are some things you can do directly in code though to solicit and force suggestions.

Comment: I got the suggestions. As I'm the only one who can access that particular Knowledge Base, that may take lots of time to appear suggestions. Because there should be many hits for the kb to get the similar questions. Thus it took more time to get the suggestions.Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Active Learning suggestions will not appear immediately after turning the feature on in the portal. They'll appear after the qna model has received enough feedback to offer up a suggestion.

See [comment](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/25638#issuecomment-467989291) I wrote back in Feb of last year regarding how suggestions are trigged and when they'll show up in the portal, in MS Docs discussion for full context of the conversation. But the main thing is this:

> When there is a low confidence score difference between the top answers, we collect weighted implicit and explicit feedback to cluster suggestions for any QnA ID.
>   => When enough feedback is collected for any given suggestion, it will show in the KB.
>
> More specifically, we cluster similar user queries to generate suggestions. When minimum required feedback is collected, only then will the suggestions show in the KB.
>
> The QnA team wants to avoid publicly divulging the exact logic of what
>   exactly is the "minimum required feedback" and how often suggestions
>   are generated (besides, the team is working on improving and
>   optimizing the logic behind active learning as well)
>
> --however to see suggestions appear in the qnamaker.ai portal:
>
> - not only ensure that you've given the bot enough **feedback**
> - but also
>     give the back end "some **time**" to allow for the suggestions to appear
>     in the portal. Again, feedback is collected when your user types in a
>     query that returns answers from QnA that have confidence scores that
>     are close together.
>
> It is also good to note that feedback is not collected in the Test
>   panel in the qnamaker.ai portal as of now. You will need to chat with
>   your bot via emulator or a channel to provide feedback to your bot
>   that it can use for active learning.

Additional resource: [48.qnamaker-active-learning-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/48.qnamaker-active-learning-bot)